# How to solve "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" in Angular7?

Tags: angular7

I'm having a 'create-profile.component.html' in angular 7 containing a form with 4 text input fields, an image picker button and a submit button. 
The submit button is the only one with type="submit".

I'm using a 'profiles.service.ts' to set-up functions for dealing with crud tasks that I inject and call in 'create-profile.component.ts'. I'm also using a FormGroup to handle the inputs.

The problem is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSUmZ.png

I looked inside the 'create-profile.component.ts' where the error points, but I can't spot any problem. The function addProfile() is injected in the component due to profilesService inside the constructor. Also, the profilesService contains the addProfile() function in the first place. On the html mark-up I can't see any problem.

create-profile.component.ts

```js
export class CreateProfileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  profile: Profile;
  isLoading = false;
  form: FormGroup;
  profileImagePreview: string;
  private mode = 'create';
  private profileId: string;
  private authStatusSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private profilesService: ProfilesService,
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authStatusSub = this.authService
      .getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe(authStatus => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]
      }),
      username: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]
      }),
      bio: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      profileImage: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required],
        asyncValidators: [mimeType]
      }),
    });
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      if (paramMap.has('profileId')) {
        this.mode = 'edit';
        this.profileId = paramMap.get('profileId');
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.profilesService.getProfile(this.profileId).subscribe(profileData => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.profile = {
            id: profileData._id,
            name: profileData.name,
            username: profileData.username,
            bio: profileData.bio,
            profileImage: profileData.profileImage,
            creator: profileData.creator
          };
          this.form.setValue({
            name: this.profile.name,
            username: this.profile.username,
            bio: this.profile.bio,
            profileImage: this.profile.profileImage,
          });
        });
      } else {
        this.mode = 'create';
        this.profileId = null;
      }
    });
  }

  onProfileImagePicked(event: Event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.form.patchValue({ profileImage: file });
    this.form.get('profileImage').updateValueAndValidity();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      ////////////////// 'as string' could be removed;
      this.profileImagePreview = reader.result as string;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  onSaveProfile() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.isLoading = true;
    if (this.mode === 'create') {
      this.profilesService.addProfile(
        this.form.value.name,
        this.form.value.username,
        this.form.value.bio,
        this.form.value.profileImage,
      );
    } else {
      this.profilesService.updateProfile(
        this.profileId,
        this.form.value.name,
        this.form.value.username,
        this.form.value.bio,
        this.form.value.profileImage,
      );
    }
    this.form.reset();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.authStatusSub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

profiles.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfilesService {
  private profiles: Profile[] = [];
  private profilesUpdated = new Subject<{ profiles: Profile[] }>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  addProfile(name: string, username: string, bio: string, profileImage: 
  File) {
    const profileData = new FormData();
    profileData.append('name', name);
    profileData.append('username', username);
    profileData.append('bio', bio);
    profileData.append('profileImage', profileImage);
    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; profile: Profile; }>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/profiles/',
        profileData
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });
  }
```

create-profile.component.html

```html
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z0 card-border">
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSaveProfile()" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        formControlName="name"
        placeholder="Full Name">
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid">Please enter a valid name.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        formControlName="username"
        placeholder="Username">
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('username').invalid">Please enter a valid username.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea
        matInput
        rows="4"
        type="text"
        formControlName="bio"
        placeholder="Bio"></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('bio').invalid">Please enter a few words about yourself.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="porofile-create-buttons-holder">
      <button mat-stroked-button type="button" (click)="profileImagePicker.click()">Choose Profile Image</button>
      <input type="file" #profileImagePicker (change)="onProfileImagePicked($event)">
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <button mat-stroked-button type="submit">Save Profile</button>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-image-preview" *ngIf="profileImagePreview !== '' && profileImagePreview && form.get('profileImage').valid">
      <img [src]="profileImagePreview" [alt]="form.value.username">
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

I expect no error. I have a literally similar component and service doing the same thing for 'posts' and works just fine.

Comment: humour me. in the call to add profile and in the else statement, the last parameter `this.form.value.profileImage,` can you remove the comma

Comment: @bilpor yes. Why?

Comment: In other languages, a comma following with nothing else can cause an internal error, because the compiler is expecting more. I wasn't sure if this would be the same issue with ANgular

Comment: @bilpor ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a lowercase-uppercase capitalization error inside the 'profile' controller of my express backend. I had to recheck all the code related to 'profile' on the server to figure this out.